# How to import sql script in sql compact database?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL server database. I wanna use the same database in sql compact edition. Actually I've been searching for it and found that there is something like sql scripting. (Task->Generate Script) So I created a script file(script.sql) but I don't know how to import this script in sql compact. The purpose is to have a .sdf database and be able to manage the database via SQL Server Compact.

I have tested softwares like primeworks(DataPort Wizard) before but it doesn't give the result because my database is too large for it.

Any suggestion to convert SQL database(.mdf) to SQL Compact(.sdf) by using script file or by another way is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which version MsSQL server you using ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Data Portal Wizard is the best tool available. Since you have a verge large DB, you can convert in small units. Like for ex : use Task->Generate Script -> tables
Generate Script -> Stored procedure
and so on.
Don't convert everything in a single go.

Let me know if this was helpful to you. Else we will think of something else.

For reference:
http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortWizard.html

Comment: Thanks, I worked with Data Port Wizard. Just when creating the database, I set the maximum size to 1024. This way, I could convert the whole access database to sql ce

Comment: Nice, thats great to hear that you were able convert the entire database and thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Right Click **DATABASE** >> **Task** >> **Generate Script** >> **next** >> **select  entire database and all database object** >> **next**  >> **save script to specific location** >> **next** >> **next**

Now open the Save script file in SQl editor 
Select All and click `!Execute`  Button